# Как составить пропорцию?

Tags: php, математика

По какой формуле рассчитать следующее:

**Дано:**

```
$width = 300;    
$height = 500.5; 
$scale = 16/9;
```

Мне нужно подобрать целые числа `$newWidth` и `$newHeight` такие, чтобы соответствовали условиям

```
$newWidth / $newHeight == $scale && 
$newWidth >= $width &&
$newHeight >= $height
```

Объясните на словах или формулой, как это насчитать?

**Есть набросок:**

```
function aloe($width, $height, $scale){
    if ($width / $height > $scale) {
        $newWidth = $width;
        $newHeight = round($width / $scale);
    } else {
        $newHeight = $height;
        $newWidth = round($height * $scale);
    }
    return $newWidth / $newHeight;
}
```

Но почему-то у результата имеется погрешность:

```
echo ( aloe(300, 500, 1.55) === aloe(233, 123, 1.55) ? "Все ок" : "Погрешность!"); //Погрешность!
```

Comment: Ну а почему бы вам не вывести промежуточный результат и не посмотреть? У вас в вычислениях `round`, так что несовпадение вполне ожидаемо.

Comment: Какого размера погрешность?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Все же логично.

1. Ваша высота должна быть кратна `9`
2. А ширина соответственно кратна `16`

Запускайте цикл, перебирайте высоты, начиная с `501`, которые по модулю `9` дадут `0`.

Т.е. `Height mod 9 == 0`

Ближайшее целое `504`, подскажу вам.

Следовательно ширина будет равна: `504 / 9 * 16 = 896`

`width    896   16
------ = --- = --
height   504    9`
Все условия выполняются.

Вот код. В `PHP` не силен, но думаю понятно будет. Выводит `True`.

```
$width = 300;
$height = 500.5;
$scale = 16 / 9;

while (round($height) % 9 != 0)
{
    $height++;
}

$new_height = round($height);
$new_width = $new_height / 9 * 16;

echo($new_height);
echo($new_width);
if (($scale == $new_width / $new_height) && ($new_width >= $width) &&     ($new_height >= $height))
{
    echo("True");
}
```

Если известно только соотношение, то тоже несложно:

```
$scale = 1.55;

$width = 1;
$height = 1;

while ($width / $height != $scale)
{
    $width++;
    $height = intval($width / 1.55);
}

echo($width);
echo($height);
```

В результате: 31 / 20

Comment: а если заранее не известно ни 16, ни 9? Известен лишь результат деления 16 на 9 или, к примеру, 1.55.

Comment: @Виталька ну восстановить деление можно обратным умножением)

Comment: @Василий Барбашев эээм, умножением на что? мы не знаем не делимое, не делитель. Только частное.

Comment: @Виталька пропустил момент, что оба могут быть не известны) Прошу прощения

Comment: @Виталька Ну а что такое 1.55, как не 31/20? :)

Comment: Добавил в ответ код. @Виталька

Comment: вместо цикла с приращением высоты можно как минимум написать так `$height = (int)(($height+8)/9) * 9` - как минимум быстрее.